# How to access build args in ENTRYPOINT dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-entrypoint, payara-micro

I am trying to deploy an app in payara micro based on payara dockerimage and I need to pass one arguement snapshotversion in ENTRYPOINT(basically i want to access the build args in ENTRYFORM) exec form, as exec form of ENTRYPOINT is preferred: my docker file is as follows:

```
FROM payara/micro:5.193.1

ARG snapshotversion
ENV snapshotvs=$snapshotversion

RUN jar xf payara-micro.jar

COPY /service/war/target/app-emailverification-service-war-${snapshotversion}.war ${DEPLOY_DIR}/
COPY ojdbc6.jar ${PAYARA_HOME}/
COPY --chown=payara domain.xml /opt/payara/MICRO-INF/domain/domain.xml

RUN cd /opt/payara/MICRO-INF/domain && ls -lrt
#ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/opt/payara/payara-micro.jar", "--deploy", "/opt/payara/deployments/app-service-war-$snapshotvs.war", "--domainConfig", "/opt/payara/MICRO-INF/domain/domain.xml","--addLibs", "/opt/payara/ojdbc6.jar"]

ENTRYPOINT java -jar /opt/payara/payara-micro.jar --deploy /opt/payara/deployments/app-service-war-$snapshotvs.war --domainConfig /opt/payara/MICRO-INF/domain/domain.xml --addLibs /opt/payara/ojdbc6.jar
```

The commented ENTRYPOINT does not work. Container logs says invalid deployment. What am i missing here? Also how can I use CMD with this. Can someone post an example.

Answer (score 1):

The commented line doesn't work, because it is an *exec* form of `ENTRYPOINT`, which doesn't invoke shell (`/bin/sh -c`), so variable substitution doesn't happening.

If you want to use an *exec* form and environment variables you need to specify it directly:

```
    ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "your command with env variable"]
```

To your question about how can you use `CMD` with this, for example like this:

```
    ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c"]
    CMD ["your command with env variable"]
```

You mentioned, that you want to use build args in `ENTRYPOINT` instruction. It's not really possible, because nor `ARG` nor `ENV` are expanded in `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement, https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#scope

Also you could take a look at [great page with best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#entrypoint) for writing Dockerfile and `ENTRYPOINT` instructions specifically.

Comment: If you're doing this, skip `ENTRYPOINT` and use `CMD your command etc` without the JSON quoting.  (Try `docker run ... ls -lrt /` on your image with this `ENTRYPOINT` setting.)

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions that complement each other:

If you're `COPY`ing a file into the image, you can give it a fixed name inside the image.  That avoids this problem.

```
WORKDIR /opt/payara
COPY service/war/target/app-emailverification-service-war-${snapshotversion}.war deployments/app-service.war
```

If you have a particularly long or involved command that you're trying to make be the main container process, wrap it in a shell script.  You want to make sure to `exec` the main container process to avoid some trouble around signal handling (resulting in `docker stop` pausing for 10 seconds and then hard-killing your actual process).

```sh
#!/bin/sh
exec java \
  -jar /opt/payara/payara-micro.jar \
  --deploy /opt/payara/deployments/app-service.war \
  --domainConfig /opt/payara/MICRO-INF/domain/domain.xml \
  --addLibs /opt/payara/ojdbc6.jar
```

```sh
COPY launch.sh ./
RUN chmod +x launch.sh
CMD ["/opt/payara/launch.sh"]
```

In this second case, it's a shell script, so you can have ordinary shell variable substitutions.